# When do I use h state or c state of LSTM?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I'm learning LSTM but I don't get when to use the `h` hidden/output state or the `c` carry/cell state. Some resources say the c state is used for encoder+decoder, but can it be used in other places?

Let's say I have an array [1,6,7,9,2,3] and I want to find out the max number, which is 9, do I use the h state or the c state?

Let's say I have an array [1,6,7,9,2,3] and I want to find out [the max profit](https://leetcode.com/problems/best-time-to-buy-and-sell-stock/), which is 8 (buy on day 0 sell on day 3), do I use the h state or the c state?

[LSTM counting numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248439/lstm-counting-numbers) uses LSTM to count how many 3's in an array of 1 to 3. For example [1,2,3,1,2] is 1. They use the h state. Why don't they use c?

If in all these cases I would use the h state, can I say that if I am merely a machine learning user instead of a hardcore Mathematician or a machine learning researcher, it's always safe to stay with the h state unless there is an established practice?

I'm familiar with tensorflow and keras if you are glad to show some code.